# Remove file extension from file name

Tags: c, fatfs

Want to remove file extension from file name but receiving "Invalid initializer" error.

```
char filename[] = sdfileinfo.fname;
        char filenameonly[64];
        int i = 0;
        while(1)
        {
            if (filename[i] == '.') break;
            filenameonly[i] = filename[i];
            i = i + 1;
        }
```

Comment: Find the *last* dot in the string (`strrchr` will help you there) and replace it with the string hull-terminator.

Comment: As fopr your problem, you can't initialize an array using a pointer or other array. You must *copy* the string instead.

Comment: You'd need: `char *filename = sdfileinfo.fname;`

Comment: If there is no '.' in the file name, the loop will run forever. Should also stop on terminating 0 and `i` reaching the size of `filenameonly`.